# Akka. Android. NoSuchMethodException: <init>

Tags: java, android, akka, proguard

When I am running application that uses Akka on Android I receive the following exception:

```
04-29 16:13:06.235: E/AndroidRuntime(8968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [interface com.typesafe.config.Config, interface akka.event.LoggingAdapter, interface java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory]
```

This exception is thrown during actor system creation:

```
Props props1 = Props.create(MyActor.class);
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
```

I assumed that proguard removed a constructor, so I added the following line to my proguard.cfg:

```
-keep class com.typesafe.**  { *; }
```

but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest.xml. It looks like you named the main activity incorrectly. It can't find your constructor.

Comment: @mttdbrd The exception is thrown my activity's onCreate method. Therefore I assume that my activity was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your constructors with the following signature is not public or doesn't exist:

```
MyActivity (com.typesafe.config.Config, akka.event.LoggingAdapter, java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)
```

Comment: You are right. I fixed my proguard.cfg according to your advice and now it works.

Comment: Great! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on mttdbrd's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366338/2369122)... For those confused how to actually get rid of this warning add the following to your proguard:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(com.typesafe.config.Config, akka.event.LoggingAdapter, java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory);
}
```